# navigator.geolocation working on browser but not on device

Tags: angularjs, cordova

I am working on an Hybrid `

```
$scope.onItemClick=function(value)
        {
        //alert('value: '+value);
        if(value=='app.vrsForm')
        { 
           alert('hello inside form');
           navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition($scope.onSuccess,$scope.onError,{maximumAge:600000, timeout:5000, enableHighAccuracy: false});
}
```

`
application where I have to detect the user's location and add an address from my list of places that are closest to it. What I found is that my code working fine on Mozilla Firefox, however it just does not seem to work on my device.

The success function shows an alert as I have placed an alert in it for the browser, but in the device it just does not seem to reach the onSuccess function.

Comment: did you install the geolocation plugin? in which device did you test?

Comment: I tested the application on my Moto G3, and it shows error code:3 and error message: timeout expired in my cellphone. I did install the plugin as it already works fine in my pc browser of Firefox.

Comment: do you have the geolocation enabled on the device? the geolocation plugin doesn't add any code, it just uses the webview geolocation and it seems that is buggy on some devices...

Comment: The geolocation plugin enables the device location on high accuracy mode (by default). However I found that once I enable the location property of my device through the current application, other applications start having issues which require access to location as well, like Uber Cabs which says that the location property for the device is not enabled, which anyways is, and is also visible.